# Finding Non-Empty Cell, Insert Row below, Cut Range and Paste in inserted Row

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to programming and am self taught, so please excuse my ignorance and mistakes.  I am trying to write a macro to find non-empty cells in column F Rows 1 to 1000 (F1:F1000), then (if data is present) insert a row beneath the value, then cut the  values from column F through J and paste the values in the newly created rows from column A to E.  It would then go to the next non-empty cell in column F and repeat.  Once it's done with column F it would go to column K Rows 1 to 1000, if data is present insert a row beneath the value, then cut the values from dolumn K through O and paste the values in the newly created rows from column A to E.  It would repeat like this through column IP (finding something in column IE, insert row beneath and cut values from IE to IP and paste in A:E.

My code is below.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub JW_Barcode()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In Range("F1:F1000")
    If rng.Value <> "" Then
        rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next
Dim a As Integer
For a = 1 To 1000
On Error GoTo NextColumn
With Columns("F:J")
    .Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).Activate
End With
Selection.Cut
With Columns("A:E")
    .Find(what:="", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).Activate
End With
ActiveSheet.Paste
Next a
NextColumn:

Dim rng2 As Range
For Each rng2 In Range("K1:K1000")
    If rng2.Value <> "" Then
        rng2.Offset(2, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next
Dim b As Integer
For b = 1 To 1000
On Error GoTo NextColumn2
With Columns("K:O")
    .Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).Activate
End With
Selection.Cut
With Columns("A:E")
    .Find(what:="", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).Activate
End With
ActiveSheet.Paste
Next b
NextColumn2:
```

Etc... until it gets to find value in column IE, cut IE:IP and paste in A:E in newly created row.

Comment: You need to rethink your logic, every time you insert a row for each 234 times you plan on doing the task, it will cause the number of your rows to grow exponentially. Because when you check column K for not "", then P, etc. you will be adding another new row for the previous new rows you added. I expect your macro will slow down and eventually lock up.

Comment: Thanks.  I have indeed had excel slow down considerably and go non-responsive.  I'll have to rethink how to set it up.